# Finding the values of an element

Tags: abstract-algebra

Let $a,b\in G$ where G is a group. Let $|a|=36$ and $\langle a^{21}\rangle=\langle b^{10}\rangle$. I need to show that b is finite and find its values.

I know that for $b$ to have a finite order, there must be the smallest integer $n$ such that $b^{n}=e$. How do I use the given facts to arrive at this conclusion?

Any hints are appreciated!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hint: raise $b$ to the $120$-th power, and use the fact that:

$(a^{21})^{12} = a^{21\cdot 12} = a^{36\cdot 7} = (a^{36})^7 = e^7 = e$.

Answer (score 0):

We have $b^{10} \in \langle a^{21}\rangle$, so $$b^{10} = (a^{21})^n$$ for some $n$. Can you use the fact that $a$ is finite to deduce that $b^{10}$ is finite? What about $b$?

Comment: Can I write $a^{(21n)}=e$ and then deduce that $b^{10}=3$?

Comment: What is the use of the fact that a has order 36 then?

Comment: You can't write $a^{21n} = e$. You need to use the fact that $a$ has order $36$ to show that $b^{10}$ is finite.

Comment: Can you explain why not?

Comment: For some fixed $n$ you have $a^{21n} = b^{10}$. You then need to raise this to some other power to get $e$

Comment: How did you get $b^{10} = (a^{21})^n$?

Comment: From the fact that $b^{10}\in \langle a^{21}\rangle$